# Selenium Automation Chrome browser opens and closes with error mesage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Good Day Ahead.
After searching numerious posts in Stackoverflow, I tried to write and implement the automation using selenium and python programming.
I tried my first code as below and i am getting error.
My browser opens and closes very fast. It throws error in the output.

Code:-

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/")
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
#browser.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/")
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Error:-

```
/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/bin/python /home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/06092022_selenium1.py 
/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/06092022_selenium1.py:9: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/06092022_selenium1.py", line 9, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/")
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/halovivek/PycharmProjects/yearcoding/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this line comes

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium_driver/")
```

After you already properly created webdriver instance with

```py
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
```

?
Looks like your code should be as following:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**UPD**
To make your browser stay opened add `"detach", True` option, as following:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: browser = webdriver.Chrome("/home/halovivek/Documents/Automation/selenium Here i have downloaded and stored the chrome web browser executable file.

Comment: You already did that with `ChromeDriverManager`. It downloads the latest Selenium version

Comment: The above code is working. But I dont want to close my browser. it closes automatically. I want my browser to stay awake.

Comment: That's another issue. I will add you a code to make browser stay opened